# how to show <div> available on 1.html page on button click event from 2.html(where button is available on another HTML page ) using JS, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

below is my code, i'm trying to load main html page containing 2 html pages in it.
button is given on one of the html page and on that button click I want to show division from another html page which is in hide condition on page load.

/* main.html file to load first */

```
<html>
    <head>
    <frameset rows="50%,51%" cols="*">
        <frame src="1.html"/>
        <frame src="2.html"/>
    </frameset>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

/*   1.html file this file is having button to clicl which covers half of the page */

```
<link href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="sidenav">
            <div class="Dropdown">
                <button class="btn" id="load">Load</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

/*     2.html file this file is having division which is hidden on page load      */

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#FirstDiv').hide();
            });
        </script>
        <body>
            <html>
                <div class="sidenav">
                    <div class="FirstDiv" id="FirstDiv">
                        <div id="infoPopup">
                            <form action="#" id="form_1" method="post" name="form_1">
                            <span>Select Name</span><br>
                            <input id="File" name="File" type="file">
                            </br><br>
                            <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Ok"/> 
                            <input type="button" id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />
                            </br>   
                            </form>
                        </div>&nbsp;
                    </div>
                </div>
            </html>
        </body>
```

/*    menu.css file contains all styles */

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 1; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.FirstDiv {
    alignment-adjust: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: i tried to write code in menu.js as
-----------------
$("#btn").click( function(){
    $("#FirstDiv").show();
});

but this didn't work.

Comment: Could you edit the title, it's too long, maybe 'how to show a div in a frame when clicking a button in other frame'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) API to handle communication from the iframe to the parent page.

Pseudologic (Hard to give working code as there are multiple pages involved)

In `1.html`:

1. Register the `Load` button to have a click handler. When the button is clicked you will need to postMessage from `1.html` to the parent page. `window.parent.postMessage("Load");`
2. You will then have to capture that event in the parent page `main.html` and runsome code to show the hidden iframe. `window.addEventListener("message", function(e){e.data==='Load'?showHiddenIframe():'';}, false);`

EDIT:

To continue the answer for the question in the comments:

**In `1.html`:**

When the user makes a selection in `1.html` you will need to postMessage from `1.html` to the parent page with possibly the division ID the user selected in `1.html`. `window.parent.postMessage("1");`

**In `main.html`**

You will then have to capture that event in the parent page `main.html` and run some code to show the hidden iframe.

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
    // Make sure you pass the division selected as parameter
    showHiddenIframe(e.data)
}, false);
```

You will also have to pass the division ID to the second iframe

```
function showHiddenIframe(division){
    var iframe2 = document.getElementById('iframe2');
    // Show the iframe
    iframe2.style.display = 'block';

    // postMessage with division ID selected to the second iframe
    iframe2.contentWindow.postMessage(division)
}
```

**In `2.html`:**

You will now have to listen for the incoming message from the parent page `main.html` like this:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
    var division = e.data;
    // Code here to show the correct division
}, false);
```

Comment: there are multiple dropdown buttons in 1.html and divisions in 2.html, and depending on the button click need to make division visible. in that case, how it will work?